# Relativistic Electrodynamics

Tags: relativity, classical-electrodynamics

What are the applications of relativistic electrodynamics I've been learning about it in a theoretical physics module however I don't understand what implications or uses it has in real life and haven't found much online was wondering if anyone could give me some topics where it has impacts ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "non-relativistic electrodynamics", so it's not clear what "relativistic electrodynamics" should be. Could you give an example of where you found that expression?

Comment: How about magnets?

Comment: This question (v1) seems like a list question.

Answer (score 2):

Electrodynamics is invariant under Lorentz transformations (though in the form that Maxwell's equations are usually written -- this invariance may not be manifest, which is why one usually resorts to the so called [Covariant formulation of electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_formulation_of_classical_electromagnetism), in terms of tensors and partial derivatives). So, in my opinion the term "relativistic electrodynamics" is a bit of a misnomer. But I can concede if some people consider this a bit pedantic.

Sometimes people use the term 'relativistic electrodynamics' to refer to the electrodynamics of particles that are relativistic. This is perhaps more in line with your question.

Relativistic electrodynamics has tons of applications: the study of electromagnetic waves, the design of antennas and analysis of radiation patterns, and of course relativistic particle motion in accelerators (e.g. the Large Hadron Collider) under complicated arrangements of electric and magnetic fields, to name a few real life applications. More formal applications include classical and quantum field theory, which are based on and build upon the relativistic (covariant) formulation of electrodynamics.